# C#: Creating lists of generic containers?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I have a situation in which I have a data container that looks something like this:

```
public class DataContainer<T> 
{
    public T GetData { get; private set; }

    public DataContainer(T data)
    {
        this.GetData = data;
    } 
}
```

But unfortunately I need to have a list of these containers where the generic parameter of each is not known until runtime and can vary from element to element. I initially attempted to run with something like:

```
IList<DataContainer<dynamic>> containerList = new List<DataContainer<dynamic>>();
containerList.add((dynamic)new DataContainer<int>(4));
containerList.add((dynamic)new DataContainer<string>("test"));
```

Which unfortunately does not work (run into a RuntimeBinderException). I initially attempted casting to (DataContainer) but I get an InvalidCastException there.

My question has two parts:

1. I understand that I'm probably abusing 'dynamic' to try to get the behavior I want, but can someone explain why the above won't work?
2. What's the best way to approach this situation? Should I push the dynamic into the 'GetData' for the DataContainer and de-genericize it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Honestly if you don't know type use common for everything, I mean Object.I really don't get what you mean when saying I will know type only at runtime. If let's say you create objects from xml then you can use Object to store them.

Comment: Do you know atleast something about types that can appear at runtime? Like if they have a common base class or interface, if they are all reference types, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
public interface IDataContainer
{
    object GetData{get;set;}
}

public class DataContainer<T> : IDataContainer
{
    public T GetData { get; private set; }

    object IDataContainer.GetData 
    {
        get { return this.GetData; }
        set { this.GetData = (T)value; }
    }

    public DataContainer(T data)
    {
        this.GetData = data;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
IList<IDataContainer> containerList = new List<IDataContainer>();

containerList.Add(new DataContainer<string>("test"));
containerList.Add(new DataContainer<int>(234));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a non-generic baseclass version of DataContainer and use that for your List's generic type